# Buffer comparing (without new line character) with a string

Tags: c, string, comparison, compare, buffer

How to compare a buffer without new line character with a string?

strcmp(buffer,"change") is not returning 0.

Comment: Without newline or without NUL terminator? Because if it's just without newline I don't see where the problem is...

Comment: you need to provide some more info. How does the strings look like?

Comment: you need to specify what content `buffer` has.

Answer (score 1):

[strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) is the function you can use to do that.

Comment: I'm guessing he asked the question to which this is the right answer, so +1 XD

Comment: @Algorithmist you must be informed of a lot more details about The Problem than me!

Answer (score 0):

From your post I assume you have a \n in 'buffer' so this will fail

```
strcmp(buffer,"change")
```

In order to compare write instead

```
strncmp(buffer,"change",strlen("change"))
```

or better

```
char keyword[] = "change";
strncmp(buffer,keyword,strlen(keyword)
```

Comment: wouldn't this return inaccurate results if buffer = "changes"? because it would only compare up to the e, and they are the same up until then.

Comment: yes, but the only way to avoid that would be to replace \n with \0 and then do a strcmp on the full strings.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the suggested `strncmp`, you can remove the `'\n'` from buffer before comparing ...

```
char buffer[WHATEVER];
if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) /* uh oh */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

{ /* validate buffer and remove trailing '\n' */
    size_t buflen;
    buflen = strlen(buffer);
    if (!buflen) /* oh uh */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (buffer[buflen - 1] != '\n') /* oh uh */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    buffer[buflen - 1] = 0;
}

if (strcmp(buffer, "change") == 0) /* "change" found */;
```